# C++: Are map elements stationary in memory?

Tags: c++, dictionary

Can we say that the elements (pairs) of an `std::map` are stationary? A quick test with g++ shows that after an element is inserted it stays at the same place in memory.

Definitions:

```
struct K { ... }; // Holds an int, prints when constructed, destructed etc..
struct V { ... }; // Holds an int, prints when constructed, destructed etc..
typedef std::map<K,V> M;
M m;
```

Debug printings after first insert:

```
======= ADDRESS #1
DEBUG: M::const_iterator i = m.find(10)
K(10)
K.~K; value == 10
DEBUG: &*i == 0x1e6b030
DEBUG: &i->first == 0x1e6b030
DEBUG: &i->second == 0x1e6b034
```

Debug printings many inserts later:

```
======= ADDRESS #2
DEBUG: M::const_iterator i = m.find(10)
K(10)
K.~K; value == 10
DEBUG: &*i == 0x1e6b030
DEBUG: &i->first == 0x1e6b030
DEBUG: &i->second == 0x1e6b034
```

Do we have any explicit or implicit guarantee in the standard that elements remain in their places in memory after they are inserted? Do we have something for the key or the value individually?

Comment: The standard has guarantees on reference and iterator validity after operations on a map. Effectively, these mean that the elements of a map are pretty robust against "moving". It is a node-based container, so many operations can be performed without affecting the location of its elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From section 23.1.2/8(Associative containers):

> The insert members shall not affect the validity of iterators and references to the container, and the erase
>   members shall invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements.

so so map elements *are* guaranteed to remain stationary in memory

Comment: It doesn't mean that the items are in the same place, it means the iterators can still be used which is not the same thing.

Comment: @egur - it also mentions references, which are just pointers underneath. So yes, it does.

Comment: BTW: In the C++11 standard, it is section 23.2.4/9.

Comment: References to the container, not the items - that's what the text says. Personally I wouldn't trust that these objects stay at the same address.

Comment: @egur the text clearly means iterators and references to *elements of* the container